# Why do I get the error "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'"?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

The following code produces the compiler error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

```
if let library = json as? [String: Any] {
    if let books = library["books"] as? Array { // On this line

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need specify the type of your `Array` object.

```
if let books = dic["books"] as? Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> { //Or as? Array<Any>

//Or

if let books = dic["books"] as? [[String: Any]] { //Or as? [Any]
```